# External users inputing into the Org

Tags: community, partner

We use appraisers to appraise real estate for us. We would like to have them login to our Org and create new appraisal records. They would be able to see a record which is a custom object which represents the deal for which they are conducting the appraisal.

My question is : What would be the best practice for this scenario ? Would you set them up as community users in an "appraiser community" in which they could only see the deals they are working on ? I'm assuming as community users I could grant them the necessary access to custom object\tab ?

Every time I try to get a good "partner" community tutorial it is always shown to me in a type of Customer Support scenario and I don't see it from this point of view. I only see them submitting Cases or searching a Knowledge Base etc....

Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communities is the overarching design that unifies the portal experiences from the prior versions (e.g. Self-Service Portal, Customer Portal, Partner Portal, etc). You can create a Community for any purpose that you need. While one of the most common examples is indeed a Support Community, you can also create a Partner Community. The definition of Partner Community (outlined in [Communities User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=0)) is:

> Business-to-business communities that need access to sales data such as partner relationship management.

However, depending on your needs, you might be able to get away with lesser licenses than Partner Community, based on this chart:

[image: Community License Guideline]

If they don't need Leads, Opportunities, or Campaigns, you might only need Customer Community or Customer Community Plus licenses.

Please discuss the specific details of your proposed scenario with your account executive to make sure you're not buying the wrong type or quantity of license. They should know the right questions to ask to make sure you get the licenses that are right for you.

Comment: So it sounds like you are recommending using a Community-based scenario. I guess it's just a matter of setting up my "appraiser community" and giving them tabs to the necessary custom objects ... ?

Comment: @Zoom_v it's *likely* that's the path you want. You can set up custom objects and tabs in communities, plus it gives you special profiles you can customize, sharing, etc. Again, consider talking to your AE to make sure it is right for you.